# Error open KMZ file from Oregon 650t Garmin

Tags: google-earth, file-formats, kmz

This is similar to this [Previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62188/can-i-import-a-kmz-file-directly-from-arcmap-10-to-garmin-gps) however; it does not mention about dpi or resolution to save a good quality image with very limited kmz files to be use for Garmin?

What is the dpi when do you save the kmz file from Google Earth Pro into Oregon 650t Garmin ? Is there a standard file number  to save a kmz  file with a specific number ?

I had a Non- user  set up his ArcMap 10.1 and export user's map to jpeg and gave them to me to geoference them in GEP .

My question Do I need to know the Map scale from ArcMap exported to jpeg file ? or regarding of what the user map scale set at and export jpeg at a higher resolution to preserve a good quality image ?

Garmin will not open kmz files greater than 1 MB ? Am I wrong ? or do I need to resize the pixel size ?

My Garmin GPS does not have usb chip in, so I am thinking I might need that for the CustomMaps folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [Garmin FAQ](https://support.garmin.com/support/searchSupport/case.faces?caseId=%7B9eb27dc0-6377-11df-f5aa-000000000000%7D):

> - More than one jpeg can preside in a kmz file.
> - Jpeg must be saved without Progressive Image (typically found under advanced option).
> - Images over 1 mega pixel (1024x1024 pixels, 512x2048 pixels, etc.) will be rendered at a reduced resolution on the unit. If this is causing a problem for your map, you can split the image and use multiple jpegs inside of one kmz file.
> - Each jpeg should be less than 3MB.
> - The max number of Custom Map JPEG images that can be loaded: Oregon 600 series (500)
> - There is no limitation on kmz file size as long as the previous limitations are met
> - Kmz files are read from \Garmin\CustomMaps directory on both the unit's internal memory and on the SD Card.

Something else to factor in, according to other support documents the native screen resolution of the Oregon unit is 155 dpi.

In part, the answer to your question will depend on what zoom level the unit will be when viewing the image and what the original image resolution is.